# Have a WordPress page with same title as custom post type “front” slug

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type `djs` and a custom taxonomy `city` with two terms: `boston` and `nyc`. So a DJ can either be tagged as Boston or NYC.

DJ profiles (a single `djs` post) are located at `/nyc-wedding-dj/joe-shmoe/`, for example, or for a Boston DJ, `/boston-wedding-dj/jane-doe/`. In other words, the rewrite slug for that custom post type is set as `%city%-wedding-dj`.

I have two regular pages called `/boston-wedding-djs/` and `/nyc-wedding-djs/` (note the plural **DJs** with an **s**) where I use a custom page template to loop through the DJs from the corresponding city and display a list of links to DJ Profiles from that page's city.

What I would like to do is to have the rewrite slug be `%city%-wedding-djs` so that the custom post type single pages "appear" (at least to google) as child pages of those pages mentioned above.

There's a conflict however, that when I change the rewrite slug for the custom post type `djs` to `%city%-wedding-djs`, I get a 404 Not Found error for the pages `/boston-wedding-djs/` and `/nyc-wedding-djs/`.

How can I have a rewrite slug with the same name as a page?

Comment: It's usually helpful to see some code. At the very least, the way you've defined (and tried to define) your rewrites.

Comment: Where does Google show "children of pages"? I get that the subpages (here, single DJ posts) should have roughly the same permalink base for SEO, but it's my understanding that each page is ranked on its own merit, whether it's a Single Post of a Post Type is more a breadcrumbs issue. I usually handle this the same way you are now - `/post-types/` is a Page with a nice overview, then `/post-type/xyz/` is the specific details about the `xyz` `post-type` - never had SEO issues with it; both come up for `post-type` Google searches

Comment: There's sometimes and odd bug in Wordpress when changing slugs, it will return a 404. Delete the pages with the same slugs, update the rewrite slug. Then goto settings > permalinks and resave the permalinks.

Answer (score 11):

This reminded me of a great blog [post](http://boyn.es/2013/09/28/stripping-slug-custom-post-types/) by Matthew Boynes on a somewhat related subject.

It's recommended to use a unique base slug, to avoid the clashes you're describing.

If you must do this and are looking for a workaround within WordPress, then it's possible to  adjust how it parses the incoming request, with the help of the [`request`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/b7f9555444a1259d7557aeeb9dabbe3b8a0982c4/wp-includes/class-wp.php#L323-L330)- or [`parse_request`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/b7f9555444a1259d7557aeeb9dabbe3b8a0982c4/wp-includes/class-wp.php#L332-L339) filter.

**Example**:

This checks if the `%city%-wedding-djs` page exists, so you don't need to update the code snippet if you later add more cities:

```
! is_admin() && add_filter( 'request', function( $query_vars )  
{
    if ( isset( $query_vars['city'] ) && ! isset( $query_vars['djs'] ) )  
    {
        $slug = $query_vars['city'] . '-wedding-djs';

        // Override if the %city%-wedding-djs page exists
        if ( get_page_by_path( $slug ) )
            $query_vars['pagename'] = $slug;
    }
    return $query_vars;
} );
```

or if you only got `boston` and `nyc` as cities and you don't need to check if the corresponding pages exists:

```
! is_admin() && add_filter( 'request', function( $query_vars )  
{
    if ( isset( $query_vars['city'] ) && ! isset( $query_vars['djs'] ) )  
    {
        $city = $query_vars['city'];
        if ( in_array( $city, array( 'boston', 'nyc' ) ) )
            $query_vars['pagename'] = $city . '-wedding-djs';
    }
    return $query_vars;
} );
```

This means that the request:

```
example.tld/nyc-wedding-djs/
```

is now treated as a `page`, and

```
example.tld/nyc-wedding-djs/joe-smhoe/
```

as a `djs` post.

Here we assume that the `page` rewrite rules have lower priority than for the `djs` post type.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using htaccess you can manually set up the redirects for those pages and they should then resolve correctly.  Add these lines :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/boston-wedding-djs/$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/boston-wedding-djs$ [NC]
RewriteRule . index\.php?pagename=boston-wedding-djs [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/nyc-wedding-djs/$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/nyc-wedding-djs$ [NC]
RewriteRule . index\.php?pagename=nyc-wedding-djs [NC,L]
```

after `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]`

You may also be able to do this with WordPress [add_rewrite_rule](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) however it already seems like they are confused so it seems that is less likely to work.

Answer (score 7):

You can't have a post and a page with the same slug.

You need to remove your page and create a template page of `archive-djs.php` and maybe a `single-djs.php` and that will display that page dynamically for you.

See this page for the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)

Comment: All three proposed solutions could solve the problem, but this is by far the least "hackish", cleanest, most future-proof solution - plus it's the only one that doesn't result in duplicate content as far as I can tell. It is always a good idea to consult the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) before doing workarounds - very often it provides a very simple solution to rather complicated problems.